# What is the meaning of 得 in 饿得受不了?

Tags: grammar

> 饿得受不了 (can't endure the hunger)

I kind of understand it, but why does 得 connect a verb with a verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

得 in 饿得受不了 is a 'degree particle' that indicates what 'degree' the adjective is at.

- 饿 = hungry
- 饿得 = hungry to the point of
- 饿得受不了 = hungry to the point of cannot endure (unbearably hungry)

another example

- 快 = fast
- 快得 = fast to the point of
- 快得像闪电  = fast to the point of like lightning (lightning fast)